Button in EditForm Not Reacting to Changes - Onchange/oninput
I am working on a Blazor project where I have a form inside a pop-up modal to edit a game in my database. I want the submit button to dynamically enable or disable based on user input changes. However, the button does not react to the changes as expected. Below are the relevant snippets:
EditForm of my Popup Modal:
<div id="myModal2" class="modal" style="display:@(showModal2 ? "center" : "none")">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close" @onclick="HideModal2">&times;</span>
        <p class="newGameHeader">עריכת המשחק</p>
        <EditForm Model="gameToEdit" OnValidSubmit="EditGame" id="EditGameForm">
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <p>שם המשחק</p>
            <InputText class="textInForm" @bind-Value="gameToEdit.GameName" @oninput="CheckForChanges" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => gameToEdit.GameName)" />
            <div>
                <p>זמן לשאלה</p>
                <InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="gameToEdit.questionTime" class="radio-group" @onchange="CheckForChanges">
                    <div style="display:inline-block">
                        <InputRadio Value="20" class="circle-radio" @attributes="@(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-value", "20" } })" />
                    </div>
                    <div style="display:inline-block">
                        <InputRadio Value="30" class="circle-radio" @attributes="@(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-value", "30" } })"  />
                    </div>
                    <div style="display:inline-block">
                        <InputRadio Value="60" class="circle-radio" @attributes="@(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-value", "60" } })"  />
                    </div>
                    <div style="display:inline-block">
                        <InputRadio Value="90" class="circle-radio" @attributes="@(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-value", "90" } })"  />
                    </div>
                    <div style="display:inline-block;">
                        <InputRadio Value="@int.MaxValue" class="circle-radio" @attributes="@(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-value", "ללא הגבלה" } })" id="lastButton" />
                    </div>


                </InputRadioGroup>
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => gameToEdit.questionTime)" />
            </div>
            <input type="button" value="ביטול" class="buttons" id="cancelButton2" @onclick="HideModal2" />
            <input type="submit" disabled="@isSubmitButtonDisabled" value="עדכון משחק" class="buttons" id="orangeButtonCreate2" />
</EditForm>
    </div>
</div>

Code handling the onchange method:
private void CheckForChanges()
    {
        var originalGame = MyGamesList.FirstOrDefault(g => g.ID == gameToEdit.ID);
        if (originalGame != null)
        {
            if (gameToEdit.GameName == originalGame.GameName && gameToEdit.questionTime == originalGame.questionTime)
            {
                
                isSubmitButtonDisabled = true; // Disable the submit button

            }
            else
            {
                
                isSubmitButtonDisabled = false; // Enable the submit button
            }
            Console.WriteLine(originalGame.GameName + gameToEdit.GameName);
            Console.WriteLine("the button is " + isSubmitButtonDisabled);
        }
    }

DTO:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace template.Shared.Models.Classes
{
    public class EditGameDTO
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "שדה חובה")]
        [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "יש להזין לפחות שני תווים")]
        [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "שם המשחק חייב להכיל מקסימום 30 תווים.")]
        public string GameName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "שדה חובה")]
        public int questionTime { get; set; }


    }


}


I tried using the code as mentioned above.
What happened is when I first type inside the InputText nothing happens. The second time I type - the button is changing.
When I delete the added Chars and the value goes back to being the same as it initiated with, the button is not going back to disabled.
What I'm trying to achieve is the dynamic change of the Button, so when ever another name shows up a user can press it, and when it stays the same / goes back to the first value it first initiated with, it will be back to disabled as changes are only available with different Values. ***This should also be implied to the RadioInputGroup values.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You can't use the @onchange event when you implement a bind: the bind process uses it.  You can however use @bind-Value:after which gets called once the bind value has been set.
Change this line:
<InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="gameToEdit.questionTime" class="radio-group" @onchange="CheckForChanges">

To:
<InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="gameToEdit.questionTime" class="radio-group" @bind-Value:after="CheckForChanges">

You should now see gameToEdit.questionTime set to the selected value followed by CheckForChanges called [and finally a component render] whenever you change the radio button.
Update
Based on comments, here's a Net 6 implemention:
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.
<EditForm Model="_value">

    <InputRadioGroup TValue="int" Value="_value" ValueChanged="OnValueChanged" ValueExpression="() => _value">
        <div>
            <InputRadio Value="0" data-value="0" /><span class="px-2">None</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <InputRadio Value="1" data-value="1" /><span class="px-2">One</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <InputRadio Value="2" data-value="2" /><span class="px-2">Two</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <InputRadio Value="3" data-value="3" /><span class="px-2">Three</span>
        </div>
    </InputRadioGroup>

</EditForm>

<div class="align-right p-2">
    <button disabled="@_isSubmitButtonDisabled" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>

<div class="bg-black text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>Value: @_value</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private int _value = 1;
    private bool _isSubmitButtonDisabled;

    private async Task OnValueChanged(int value)
    {
        _value = value;
        await OnAfterChange();
    }

    private Task OnAfterChange()
    {
        _isSubmitButtonDisabled = false;
        if (_value == 0)
            _isSubmitButtonDisabled = true;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}


Hi There! Thanks for answering my questions so fast.
I have changed this line as suggested, but I've encountered this error:
CS8974: A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree.
and this error:
CS0017 - 'RuntimeHelpers' does not contain a definition for 'CreatedInferredBindSetter".

Is there anything on you're mind that could be the cause for this? Should I add anymore snippets?

---NOTE---
I'm using .NET 6

That explains it.  See my updated answer.

Hey, thanks again for the quick response. That's EPIC.

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble with implementing this into my code.
The radio buttons are designed to have the content of the attribute inside the radio buttons.
Should I be able to still use @attributes to use data-value as an attribute?
If so, that should do it, and if I keep the code snippets as it was, the button should change to disable.

See revised answer.
